# PHP is_dir don't find folder

Tags: php

I want to loop through a directory and echo all folders. However, the foreach-loop just echo out . and ..

```
$dir = 'content/';
$handle = scandir($dir);
foreach ($handle as $file) {
    if (is_dir($file)) { echo '<br>' . $file; }
}
```

Here is the content of the directory:

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it :-) Plus one, but you ought to post an answer

Comment: @Mawg :) Great minds

Comment: Have you checked the permissions in that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go using this:

```
$dir = 'content/';
$handle = scandir($dir);
foreach ($handle as $file) {
    if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) { echo '<br>' . $file; }
}
```

Comment: Basically the point is that `scandir` doesn't include the path, just the last item.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I must have read and tried the code you provided wrong. Your answer will be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the only 2 Directories in that Directory are the . and .. folders. The FILES are not folders. So if you want to see the files, try

```
$dir = 'content/';
$handle = scandir($dir);
foreach ($handle as $file) {
    if ( ! is_dir($file)) { echo '<br>' . $file; }
}
```

Comment: But there is a folder: about

Comment: Ah yes I see now

Comment: Then your code should work. What OS are you working on?

Comment: MacOS Sierra, version 10.

Comment: Is `about` a symlink?

Comment: `about` is not a symlink

Comment: There seem to be something strange going on here: as I loop through the files with is_file, it just echoes out DS_Store and none of the other files.

Comment: I dont see a `DS_Store` in the example you show us.

Comment: DS_Store is a file that stores custom attributes of its containing folder in MacOS.